# What exactly means {0},{1},{2} [...] in C# list?

Tags: c#

I'm learning c# and i've seen it `{0},{1}` [...]. What it means?

Example:

```
    Console.WriteLine("\nContains(\"1734\"): {0}",
    parts.Contains(new Part {PartId=1734, PartName="" }));
```

Comment: Take a look at [C# Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholders for argument substitution during string format. Those will be replaced with actual values. In your case `x`, `y`, `z`, `result`. You can write:

```
Console.WriteLine("The average of {0}, {1} and {2} is: {3}", x, y, z, result);
```

as

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The average of {0}, {1} and {2} is: {3}", x, y, z, result));
```

Which can be optimized using latest C# syntax (feature is called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)):

```
Console.WriteLine($"The average of {x}, {y} and {z} is: {result}");
```

This last line is pretty clear for what it does.

You can optionally specify output style (number of significant digits, leading zeroes etc.) - see this for syntax and examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: So it's the same thing as Console.WriteLine("The average of " + z + ", " + y + " and " + z + " is " + result);

Comment: But shortened??

Comment: @EverytimeIdid: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it you will see the result.
It will put x, the parameter at 0 index in the {0}
It will put y in the {1} and so on
Best to play around.
Although most people use the
 $" the value of X is {x}";